# Three.js - Adding JSON file type to SceneLoader

Tags: json, three.js, progress, loader

Using http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_scene as an example, I am trying to add a js file exported from Blender.  The file loads correctly with the JSONLoader, but now I would like it to be in combination with other files plus having a progress bar.

```
            $( "progress" ).style.display = "block";

            THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() );

            var loader = new THREE.SceneLoader();

            loader.addGeometryHandler( "binary", THREE.BinaryLoader );
            loader.addGeometryHandler( "ctm", THREE.CTMLoader );
            loader.addGeometryHandler( "vtk", THREE.VTKLoader );
            loader.addGeometryHandler( "stl", THREE.STLLoader );

            loader.addHierarchyHandler( "obj", THREE.OBJLoader );
            loader.addHierarchyHandler( "dae", THREE.ColladaLoader );
            loader.addHierarchyHandler( "utf8", THREE.UTF8Loader );
            loader.addHierarchyHandler( "json", THREE.JSONLoader );

            loader.callbackProgress = callbackProgress;

            loader.load( "scenes/test_scene.js", callbackFinished );
```

I added the json HierarchyHandler and included the JSONLoader.js file.

```
loader.addHierarchyHandler( "json", THREE.JSONLoader );
```

And then I added this to test_scene.js under "objects" where other dae and obj files are.

```
"tree" : {
    "type": "json",
    "url" : "models/json/tree.js",
    "position" : [ -43, -10, 27 ],
    "rotation" : [ -1.57, 0, 0 ],
    "scale"    : [ 5, 5, 5 ],
    "visible"  : true
            },
```

The console logs that it reads the texture files referenced for the tree but never finishes - the progress bar remains at 99%.

But the error that I receive is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromArray' of undefined     SceneLoader.js:554
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening or what I'm doing wrong? The three.js example loads all types of files except json. Could there a reason for that or am I just missing something? I've read that SceneLoader is to be depreciated and I should consider using ObjectLoader but there are no example of how to do so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that the SceneLoader example that comes with Three.js includes a JSON. If I'm not mistaken, the Scene Loader is in fact capable of loading JSON files per se, without requiring any HierarchyHandler.

I actually think that your attempt in adding the JSONLoader.js file is not really linking anything.

I had a look at the example: webgl_loader_scene.html. If you open the related scene (test_scene.js) you can find an actual JSON geometry between the imports:

```
"embeds": {

    "cube_fvc": {

        "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 3
        },

        "scale" : 1.0,

        "materials": [{
            "DbgColor" : 15658734,
            "DbgIndex" : 0,
            "DbgName" : "Material",
            "colorAmbient" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            "colorDiffuse" : [0.8, 0.8, 0.8],
            "colorSpecular" : [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
            "specularCoef" : 50,
            "transparency" : 1.0,
            "vertexColors" : true
        }],

        "vertices": [1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,0.999999,1.000000,1.000001,-1.000000,1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000,1.000000,-1.000000],

        "morphTargets": [],

        "normals": [],

        "colors": [16777215,16769421,16769424,8454135,15195931,7299839,16586715,16711687,1056014,6029475,13762484,9044089,7962349,6772991,16774622,4144383,11973887,1966063,1056285,9081232,13696943,5002581],

        "uvs": [[]],

        "faces": [131,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,131,4,7,6,5,0,4,5,6,7,131,0,4,5,1,0,0,8,9,10,131,1,5,6,2,0,0,11,12,13,131,2,6,7,3,0,14,15,16,17,131,4,0,3,7,0,18,19,20,21]

    }

},
```

So I think that all you need to do is to refer a JSON file in the same syntax required by the SceneLoader.